# Controller receiving wrong parameter value from Javascript post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i just created a Javascript function and a controller method based on another one that is working as expected. Javascript value seems to be right, but when it reachs the controller, it is changed to 0. I tried re-doing the entire function from scratch with the same results.

**Edit: on console log, e has the right value**.

**Edit 2: this is how it looks the request. the number is OK!** and it is the same way the other method gets the number.

[image: this is how it looks the request]

This is the javascript code, where e is the correct value (it is the post ID):

```
 function toggleArchivar(e) { //i've debugged it and e has the correct value
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/submissions/togglearchivar/" + e,
         success: function (t) {
             t.success ? (t.data ? $("#submissionid-" + e + " p.title").prepend('<span title="archivado" class="flair
 linkflairlabel" id="archivadoTag">archivado</span>') :
 $("#archivadoTag").remove(), $("#toggleArchivar").html("nsfw")) :
 $("#toggleArchivar").html(t.error.message)
         },
         error: function () {
             alert("Error al intentar archivar.")
         }
     }) }
```

And this is the controller method:

```
 [Authorize]
 [HttpPost]
 [VoatValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 [PreventSpam(5)]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ToggleArchivar(int submissionID) //SubmissionID comes with a 0!!!
 {
     using (var repo = new Repository(User))
     {
         var response = await repo.ToggleArchivar(submissionID);
         return JsonResult(response);
     }
 }
```

Take for example the working ones, which i debugged and the value matches:
Javascript:

```
 function toggleNSFW(e) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/submissions/togglensfw/" + e,
         success: function (t) {
             t.success ? (t.data ? $("#submissionid-" + e + " p.title").prepend('<span title="Not Safe For Work" class="flair
 linkflairlabel" id="nsfwflair">NSFW</span>') :
 $("#nsfwflair").remove(), $("#togglensfw").html("nsfw")) :
 $("#togglensfw").html(t.error.message)
         },
         error: function () {
             alert("Error al intentar poner NSFW.")
         }
     }) }
```

Controller:

```
 [Authorize]
 [HttpPost]
 [VoatValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 [PreventSpam(5)]
 public async Task<ActionResult> ToggleNSFW(int submissionID)
 {
     using (var repo = new Repository(User))
     {
         var response = await repo.ToggleNSFW(submissionID);
         return JsonResult(response);
     }
 }
```

As you can see, my functions are a copy of the previous ones. I can't tell why is it coming with that value!

Comment: did you try console log e value ?

Comment: yes I did, it is the right value

Comment: What do you have in the RouteConfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for a `int` type variable is 0. As a result since the `submissionID` is not getting bound the variable is having the default value.

Check the `RouteConfig` (usually available within `App_Start` folder). There might be routes written for the `ToggleNSFW` action but not for your action - `ToggleArchivar`.

Add the following route and check if it works:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ToggleArchivar",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{submissionID}",
        defaults: new { controller ="YourControllerName", action = "ToggleArchivar", submissionID = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Replace "YourControllerName" name with the actual name of the controller.

Another option is to rename the `submissionID` parameter to the `id` so that default model binder would bind the value.

Comment: oh, wow, i think this is what i'm missing! I have no access to the DB from my office, but i'll check as soon as i arrive home!